# 'When an item is created or modified' trigger not firing until manually saved

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm running into an odd issue where my Flow will not trigger correctly upon modifying a list item. I have flow set up to copy appended Col1 content to Col2 which can then be listed as an 'updated comment' in my list's default view.

It's the same logic as a SP2013 workflow I've been using, but for whatever reason the flow will not automatically trigger when an item is created/modified in my list - it will only trigger if I go back into the flow and manually save it (the Flow) again. Additionally, if I manually save the Flow a second time, it wipes Col2's existing content.

I am not intimately familiar with any quirks found in the 'When an item is created or modified' SharePoint trigger in Flow, but it's possible I'm missing something obvious.

Below is the logic I'm using.

['Comment Update' MS Flow example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMBBP.png)

Any help would be much appreciated, I haven't been able to find any posts going over this Flow trigger specifically. It seems like there would either be a very obvious solution to this, or this is a glaring bug with Flow.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you aware of 5 mins delay for the trigger to kick start the process? It depends on your subscription. Or you have waited a long time and having this issue?