# "When an Item is created or modified" PowerAutomate trigger not firing

Tags: power-automate

There are no answers to previous questions on this.  ['When an item is created or modified' trigger not firing until manually saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240452/when-an-item-is-created-or-modified-trigger-not-firing-until-manually-saved)

Basically, when I set up the trigger using the MS Flow / Power Automate Sharepoint trigger "When an Item is created or modified", it only fires when an item is created in a list...  it is NOT fired when the list item is modified.  This is using Sharepoint 'modern' in an enterprise O365 environment.

My Flow looks like this:
[image: When an Item is created or modified sharepoint trigger in powerautomate flow]

My list looks like this: 
[image: Sharepoint list]

If I edit the item and change 'CompName" to something else, the above Flow does not trigger in PowerAutomate.  It DOES trigger when I create the new item, just not when I modify it.

Comment: If you have O365 license with free flows, it usually takes **4 - 5 minutes** before flow is triggered. However, after item creation/modification just `Edit` your flow and hit `Save` without modifying anything. This works for me and always triggers the flow instantly if there are any pending requests.

Comment: It works for my example. I see you have set up a send email action. Do you get any emails when you create and/or modify?

Comment: Also, can you check the runs for the flow (open My Flows tab in Power Automate, click on your flow and see the runs.) You can click each run to see more and it may help show what's going on in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The flows run.  The 5 minute delay made it appear as if they weren't running.